# How can I get result of jquery.data(element).actions through file .js?

Tags: jquery, expando

If I write in Chrome console:

```
let btns =  document.getElementsByName('btn_desktop');
let btnLast = btns[btns.length - 1];
jQuery.data(btnLast).actions;
```

I get the following result in the Chrome console:
`[{\"oper\":\"viewLink\",\"link\":\"here link"}]`

- [screen1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJJYV.png)

If I run same script through sender.js after clicking <kbd>alt+h</kbd> then I get the result `undefined` 
How can I get result like in console?

- [screen2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DT2eO.png)

Comment: Can you share the code of sender.js? and also your HTML?

Comment: sender.js contains same like console. It's same.
Sorry, I cant share HTML cause that's product of bank. I signed a non-disclosure agreement :(

"btn_desktop" has jQueryID, for example jQuery220038880947233794342
Through jQueryID I can get a link to page of client of bank.
If runs code directly in Chrome terminal - jQueryID found. 
If runs from file .js - undefined